# Github and Heroku Branching Deployment Strategy without Conflicts

Tags: git, github, heroku, merge, branch

I have one repo that is attached/connected 2 Heroku Apps: 'prod' and 'dev'.

In the github repo.. when code is merged to "master" branch = 'prod' app is deployed, and when code is merged to a branch called "dev" in that repo = 'dev' app is deployed.

Now, we use the "dev" branch and app as a full testing app, before pushing to master. So ALL developers first create their own feature branch from "dev" branch.. then self-test or QA helps them test because they merge their app into "dev" (which connects to the app in heroku)
Note: the workflow is something like this:
"master" merges into the feature branch > then the feature branch merges into "dev" branch

- git checkout [feature branch]
- git merge master
- git checkout dev
- git merge --squash [feature branch]
- git push

So then, when all self-testing is done on 'dev' app in Heroku, we merge a PR from our feature branch to "master" branch, which deploys to 'prod' app in Heroku.

The PROBLEM:

- We always have to make sure our "dev" branch and "master" branch are in-sync - so all the developers working on this ONE REPO have to constantly face MERGE conflicts and always have to git pull and merge/sync their feature branches into "dev" branch - and also merge/sync with "master" branch.
- This can happen MANY times a day - because so many developers are just creating feature branches of this ONE "dev" branch and self-test on it. Then they also constantly merge into "master"... So, because of these constant changes and merges into "master" - they also have to keep their feature branch and the "dev" branch in-sync with "master" branch - which takes a lot of time and is just annoying at times.

What github branching and testing strategy can we implement to make sure that we change this into a smooth workflow.. without all these problems?

OK SO UPDATE:

As mentioned the "dev" branch is pushed locally from every developers local/terminals - that is why there are so many conflicts.

- I agree that the developers can self-test on their locals - but as the 'dev' app is kind of like our "testing" app (also has many data from production): we need to make sure it is also up to date and we can at-least test on it before merging PR into master from our feature branch.

Now what we want to do is implement TRUNK BASED deployment on this - with feature flags enabled. Even though this process is still somewhat trunk-based, we want to improve it and add feature flags to it. So the process should be something like:

PR of feature branch from and into "master" (the trunk - where every developer will merge their code) -> we will have feature flags enabled so they can turn on/off their features as needed!

Now, my question is: How do we still make sure our "dev" branch and "dev" heroku app is always in-sync with master when we go with this trunk-based approach. Because then the trunk branch is "master" which is production. How do we still get the developers also push to "dev" branch (but NOT locally)??

Comment: Conflicts are normal and not something to be *avoided*, but, if two different developers want to test their development, they should have two different Heroku repositories to which to send their to-be-tested commits. That way they do their testing independently, using independent Heroku repositories. The fact that they're working on stuff that will *eventually* be re-shared is not important here, what matters is that Heroku only deploys from one name, so they each have to have a private Heroku instance (just like they each have a private clone).

Comment: "We always have to make sure our "dev" branch and "master" branch are in-sync" - dev shouldn't be required to be in sync with master (I don't understand why you have this requirement). Also, devs (in some cases) can just run development locally - why does "self-testing" require deployment to heroku. Just food for thought.

Comment: @torek we do local testing but the problem comes when we have to push to the "dev" for testing (which is kind of like our actual QA app) - please see update to my question.. ty

Comment: @topsail the "dev" should be in-sync with master because our 'dev' app is basically our QA/Staging APP which also has similar data as prod - so that is why we want to test in dev before merging in "master". The developers do local testing but we also want to test in 'dev'. Also, please see my UPDATE in question . ty

Comment: Hmmm, well I don't think devs should be frequently updating any main/master branches or staging branches either. That is where I would want to have a development branch (with feature branches). It sounds like a catch-22. You want devs to be able to merge into the staging branch so they can test there, but you also don't want them to do that because it causes problems with merge conflicts and lots of troublesome merges and commits. Anyway, imho that is not how a staging branch should be used anyway - but I don't I really have any good advice to give here so hopefully other experts can chime in.